# EditorInstance.document.getById("some id") returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor-4 in my application and in my coding i want to get the element by its id. below code is returning the element in FF and IE but its returning **null in Google Chrome**.

```
var ele = EditorInstance.document.getById("id_1");
```

Any alternate is there to get element by its id in Google Chrome.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try searching the element with this id 'id_1' in chrome's developer's panel or viewing page source. That can help you figure out if element is not in the page at all or it is with some different id.

Comment: thanks Pawan... i've already tested and element with that **id is present** in the page. but its not getting.

Comment: Hmm... in which place of your page are you trying to access the element? You can try accessing it at the end of the page(right before the closing body tag) if not already or in document.ready function if you are using jquery. These are just tries

Comment: in $("#btn").click(function() i am calling one function getDetails() and in this function only i am trying to get ...

Answer (score 0):

Check what if you used a native method:

```
EditorInstance.document.$.getElementById( 'id_1' );
```

If this one is also `null`, make sure that your `id` is correct. `id`s are case-sensitive, so `iD_1` != `id_1`.

`document.getById` implementation is very simple:

```
getById: function( elementId ) {
    var $ = this.$.getElementById( elementId );
    return $ ? new CKEDITOR.dom.element( $ ) : null;
},
```

There's a very small chance, that something is really broken here.

Answer (score 0):

previously i was using

```
 content = EditorInstance.getData(); 
 EditorInstance.setData(content);"
```

due to which it was not working in chrome.

but now i am using

```
content = rootElement.getHtml(); 
rootElement.setHtml(content);
```

and its working fine...